# How to read the mimetype of any file that is uploaded with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, mime-types, whitelist

I am trying to figure out the mimetype for any file that is uploaded to my server. I have no problem determining if something is a pdf/jpg/png but I am uncertain how to determine if the provided file is a .csv or .zip.

If I decode a .zip and search for it's mimetype, it will return the mimes of the files within the .zip, instead of the mimetype of .zip. I cannot find the extension for the .csv because when I decode the .csv it just returns it's contents as comma separated strings.

My goal is to only whitelist what I want and reject all others. How would I do this without using something like multer?

Side note, how do you determine a files name from a decoded buffer or should I have the name sent separately from the front-end?

Comment: Why would you unzip the file and check the file contents to check if it's a .zip file? Why wouldn't you just use any of the mime type checker modules? Note that there is a limit to how closely you can determine the "real" mimetype, e.g., a CSV file could legitimately contain a single line with no commas.

Comment: I don't want to unzip the file, I want to reject any compressed file, .zip/.tar/etc. Just want to whitelist a small number of them. And the extension we all know if not valid, anyone can just change image.jpg to image.png but it isn't actually converted to png by doing that. As a simple example.

Comment: So you want a fingerprinting mimetype library; I'm sure they exist. With the understanding there are limits. More or less what I said before. But you explicitly stated you "decode a zip and search for its mimetype", which makes no sense, because a zip file already has a known mimetype, and checking the mimetypes of the files in the archive is useless in determining the mimetype of the file they were extracted from--none of that flow makes any sense to me.

Comment: Sorry, that was my semantic mistake. I meant that when I decode the buffer, I cannot find the mimetype but you can search for PDF/JPG etc after doing so with images for example. I tried using file-type.js and even if doesn't return a mime for .csv but it does for .zip. so that it more important.